# Customizing the 'Hue' colors used in Seaborn Barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using seaborn to create the following chart:

[image]

I'd like to customize the colors that are generated by `hue` , preferably to set the order of the colors as Blue, Green, Yellow, Red.
I have tried passing a color or a list of colors to the `color` argument in `sns.barplot` however it yields either gradients of the color or an error.

Please Advise.

*You can use the following code to reproduce the chart:*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Early': {'A': 686, 'B': 533, 'C': 833, 'D': 625, 'E': 820},
 'Long Overdue': {'A': 203, 'B': 237, 'C': 436, 'D': 458, 'E': 408},
 'On Time': {'A': 881, 'B': 903, 'C': 100, 'D': 53, 'E': 50},
 'Overdue': {'A': 412, 'B': 509, 'C': 813, 'D': 1046, 'E': 904}})

df_long = df.unstack().to_frame(name='value')
df_long = df_long.swaplevel()
df_long.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_long.columns = ['group', 'status', 'value']
df_long['status'] = pd.Categorical(df_long['status'], ["Early", "On Time", "Overdue", "Long Overdue"])
df_long = df_long.sort_values("status")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18.5, 10.5))

g = sns.barplot(data=df_long, x='group', y='value', hue='status', ax=ax)

for bar in g.patches:
    height = bar.get_height()
    ax.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2., 0.5 * height, int(height),
                ha='center', va='center', color='white')
plt.xticks(fontsize=12)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', prop={'size': 14})

ax.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `hue` variable of [`seaborn.barplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)
is mapped via `palette`:

> **palette:** *palette name, list, or dict*
>
> Colors to use for the different levels of the `hue` variable. Should be something that can be interpreted by [`seaborn.color_palette()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.color_palette.html), or a dictionary mapping hue levels to matplotlib colors.

So to customize your `hue` colors,

- either define a color list:

  ```py
  palette = ['tab:blue', 'tab:green', 'tab:orange', 'tab:red']
  ```
- or a `hue`-color dictionary:

  ```py
  palette = {
      'Early': 'tab:blue',
      'On Time': 'tab:green',
      'Overdue': 'tab:orange',
      'Long Overdue': 'tab:red',
  }
  ```

And pass that to `palette`:

```py
sns.barplot(data=df_long, x='group', y='value', hue='status',
    palette=palette, ax=ax)
```

[image: barplot with custom palette]

Comment: You don't need to call `color_palette` explicitly; just pass the list of colors to `palette`.

Comment: Can you pass hex code colors using this same methodology?

Comment: I would recommend passing `saturation=1` as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062793/inconsistent-colours-from-custom-seaborn-palette